# How to use firebase to update your Android App

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I've seen that there are ways to update an app with Firebase Remote Config. Some sort of "Force Update" Notification. If anyone can explain it to me, that would be great.

Comment: You can check out the remote configuration introduction and documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use Firebase to update your Android App?

There are multiple ways in which you can update an Android app. The first one would be to store data in a database. Firebase has two **real-time** databases, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). You can one or the other, according to the use case of your app. For that I recommend you check the following resource:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

When it comes to Remote Config, please notice that nowadays you can [propagate Remote Config updates in real-time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime). That being said, there is no need to force anything. So I highly recommend that a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

For Force update  in a simple case the idea is

1. with firebase remort config sends the version number  which you want for your application to be forced
2. then compare remort version  with the local application version
3. if there is a mismatch then show a permanent dialog  (cancelable=false)  with a button  when the user clicks on that button to open the application in the play store .

Check out this Small Class created for force update with remort config

```
class ForceUpdateChecker(private val context: Context, private val onUpdateNeededListener: OnUpdateNeededListener?) {
interface OnUpdateNeededListener {
    fun onUpdateNeeded(updateUrl: String?)
}

fun check() {
    val remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
    if (remoteConfig.getBoolean(KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED)) {
        val currentVersion = remoteConfig.getString(KEY_CURRENT_VERSION)
        val appVersion = getAppVersion(context)
        val updateUrl = remoteConfig.getString(KEY_UPDATE_URL)
        if (!TextUtils.equals(currentVersion, appVersion)
            && onUpdateNeededListener != null
        ) {
            onUpdateNeededListener.onUpdateNeeded(updateUrl)
        }
    }
}

private fun getAppVersion(context: Context): String {
    var result = ""
    try {
        result = context.packageManager
            .getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionName
        result = result.replace("[a-zA-Z]|-".toRegex(), "")
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message!!)
    }
    return result
}

class Builder(private val context: Context) {
    private var onUpdateNeededListener: OnUpdateNeededListener? = null
    fun onUpdateNeeded(onUpdateNeededListener: OnUpdateNeededListener?): Builder {
        this.onUpdateNeededListener = onUpdateNeededListener
        return this
    }

    fun build(): ForceUpdateChecker {
        return ForceUpdateChecker(context, onUpdateNeededListener)
    }

    fun check(): ForceUpdateChecker {
        val forceUpdateChecker = build()
        forceUpdateChecker.check()
        return forceUpdateChecker
    }
}

companion object {
    private val TAG = ForceUpdateChecker::class.java.simpleName
    const val KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED = "force_update_required"
    const val KEY_CURRENT_VERSION = "force_update_current_version"
    const val KEY_UPDATE_URL = "force_update_store_url"
    fun with(context: Context): Builder {
        return Builder(context)
    }
}}
```

Call this like this in baseActivity (or from your landing page  just not in splash screen)

```
ForceUpdateChecker.with(this).onUpdateNeeded(this).check();
```

In application on create add this

```
val firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
    // set in-app defaults
    val remoteConfigDefaults: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    remoteConfigDefaults[ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED] = false
    remoteConfigDefaults[ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_CURRENT_VERSION] = "1.0"
    remoteConfigDefaults[ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_URL] =
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.com.classified.pems"
    firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(remoteConfigDefaults)
    firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(60) // fetch every minutes
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG, "remote config is fetched.")
                firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you say "compare remote version with local application version", do you mean the version in the app or in Firebase?

Comment: checkout remote config on firebase ,  in remote config   set force_update_current_version = 2.0   force_update_required = true    force_update_store_url = application store url ,                 then check     Application version is application version less then 2.0   show update dialog